# BOT Get element in a web site to a database

Tags: html, database, web, bots

I want to make a bot who collect information on a website (here backmarket) to put it in a database.

In backmarket, you can sell phone by entering information such as its storage, its status...
[backmarket sell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD9RM.png)

When you've done that, your link page will contain these informations like you can see

> https://www.backmarket.fr/fr-fr/buyback-funnel/device/telephone/smartphone#brand=apple&model=iPhone%2011&nextStep=false&sim_lock=1&state_body=2&state_functional=1&state_screen=2&storage=64

So you can modify information directly in this link like for example if you change the storage storage value to 128, the web site will understants that you are selling a phone with 128 GO.

But to get the estimate price you have to click on a button [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2snmk.png) and you will get the phone estimate price on another page

> https://www.backmarket.fr/fr-fr/buyback-funnel/device/telephone/smartphone/offer/519406

The problem is that this link page wont change if I modifie phone information but the price will. So I need a way to make a bot who I gave the page link like that "https://www.backmarket.fr/fr-fr/buyback-funnel/device/telephone/smartphone#brand=apple&model=iPhone11&nextStep=false&sim_lock=1&state_body=2&state_functional=1&state_screen=2&storage=64", the bot will have to click on the button show the estimate price. After that the bot will have to get the price and put it in a database.

Unfortunatly, I have no idea where to start and how to do it so if someone could help me please !

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+scrape+price+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.